# How to fix a simple variable problem in C#?

Tags: c#, virtual-keyboard

I am trying to fix a line of code in my project in C # using String as a variable but it gives me an error, I have tried several ways to fix it, but I can't reach the solution? What do you recommend to fix my problem?

```
//The problem.

            string Key1;
            string KeyHelper;
            KeyHelper = "VirtualKeyCode.VK_"; 
            Key1 = KeyHelper+"W";

         while(true)
            {
               sim.Keyboard.KeyDown(Key1);               
            }

//The Result I want to reach.

sim.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.VK_W);
```

This is the error that visual studio gives me:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode'
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear and self-explanatory. A `string` is not a `VirtualKeyCode`. It's a string. They're not even close to being the same thing.

Comment: You want `Enum.Parse(typeof(VirtualKeyCode), "VK_W")`

Comment: And how I can fix it, After all that's what my question is about, I understand the error.

Comment: I try the Mathias Method but visual studio throws the following: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting with a string and attempting to pass that to a method which accepts an enum.  So you need to use `Enum.Parse()`.  Keep in mind that `Enum.Parse()` returns `object`, so you need to cast the result to the correct enum type.

Change this:

```
sim.Keyboard.KeyDown(Key1);
```

To this:

```
sim.Keyboard.KeyDown((VirtualKeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(VirtualKeyCode), Key1));
```